# Include image in R packages

Tags: r, package

I am trying to create a package for my company where there would be some custom color palettes and our company logo. I successfully built the package that contains all the required color palettes so far, however I am stuck when trying to include the logo as well.

I thought once the logo is loaded into R, it is just another data frame and I could simply use this function to store it:

```
logo <-  image_read("logo.png")
logo <- image_scale(logo, "50")    
usethis::use_data(logo,company_logo)
```

However, I encountered an error:

> Error: Image pointer is dead. You cannot save or cache image objects
>   between R sessions.

Now I am not sure if my objective would be possible?

Comment: Try saving the images in `man/figures` not `data`

Comment: I am not sure how I am supposed to do that? Note that I am trying to find a way to include a function to load the logo when called, not used the image in a help file.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can install additional files in subdirectories under `inst` in your package. For example create a directory `inst/logos` in you package and put your logos there. When the package is installed this creates a directory `logos` in your package directory. Then you can use `system.file` to access the images when the package is installed. You could create a function in your package that does this for you. For example:

```
company_logo <- function() {
  magick::image_read(system.file("logos/logo.png", "MyCompanyPackage"))
}
```

The reason that storing the result of `image_read` using `save` doesn't work, is that the result returned by `image_read` is a pointer to some memory allocated by the package. When saving the result only the pointer is saved not the data pointed to.

Comment: Works great for me.